# Incompatible version types for quartz and commons logging

Tags: c#, logging, quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I have tried many different combinations of both the DLLs. Its always throwing this error. How can I overcome this error? Please advice.

Comment: Where is your actual error? Where is your DLL information? Any links to where you got the DLL's and what "combinations" you have tried? What sort of application are you making? What is your project framework?

Comment: My car is making a noise.  Does anyone know what it is?

Answer (score 0):

Download and install Nuget package manager and then right click on "references" and click on "Manage Nuget Packages". Then search for "Quartz.net". This will download you appropriate commons and quartz dlls.